# VBA macro crashes Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I should preface this by saying that I am extremely new to VBA, and programming in general. This is one of my first Excel macros.

What I want this macro to do is to cut a selection (I cut a lot of single rows in this worksheet), wait for it to be pasted, then to run the ASAPUtilities function Delete All Empty Rows on the worksheet that I have cut the row from. My current code crashes Excel, unsurprising as I have barely an idea of what I'm doing:

```
Sub CutDelete() ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+X 

Dim lastAction As String
        If Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").Enabled = True Then
        lastAction = Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").List(1)
        End If
    Selection.Cut

        Dim Notpaste As String
        If Left(lastAction, 5) <> "Paste" Then Notpaste = "True"

        While Notpaste = "True"
            Application.CutCopyMode = True
        Wend

End Sub

Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Application.Run "'ASAP Utilities.xlam'!ASAPRunProc", 232 'delete empty row
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Which one is causing the crash?  There's no exit condition from your `While` loop - it's not clear what that's supposed to be doing though?

Comment: Type `Option Explicit` at the top of your code module and then compile the program (first item in the `Debug` menu). This will reveal that your program doesn't have any basic errors preventing compilation.

Comment: And yes I agree with Tim, there is nothing in your While loop to change the value of `Notpaste` to False and allow loop exit. If `Notpaste` gets set to True above in the code, that will create an infinite While loop.